# After GNOME Shell extension's monkey-patching, this.parent is unexpected

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell-extensions

For the [raise-activated](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/530/alt-tab-mod-only-raise-activated-window/) GNOME Shell 3.16 extension I'm trying to monkey-patch the `AppSwitcherPopup._finish` method. Like the [original](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/altTab.js#L236), the patched version calls `this.parent`:

```js
function _modifiedFinish(timestamp) {
    // ...monkey-patched code...
    this.parent(timestamp);
}

function enable() {
    _originalFinish = AltTab.AppSwitcherPopup.prototype._finish;
    AltTab.AppSwitcherPopup.prototype._finish = _modifiedFinish;
}
```

([full code](https://github.com/lastorset/gs-ext-alttabmod-raise-activated/blob/e5f1b160c11f0c0f3bd3214c15eceebb9de8a692/extension.js))

But I get this stack trace in the console (from running `gnome-shell --replace`):

```js
(gnome-shell:24452): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: TypeError: The method '_keyReleaseEvent' is not on the superclass
_parent@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/lang.js:129
_modifiedFinish@/home/lastorset/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/Alt_Tab_Mod_Only_Raise_Activated_Window@dsboger.com.br/extension.js:34
SwitcherPopup<._keyReleaseEvent@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/switcherPopup.js:199
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/lang.js:169
```

In this case, `SwitcherPopup._keyReleaseEvent` is calling `this`, and `this` *should* be an instance of the `AppSwitcherPopup` subclass. I believe `this.parent` should be the same after patching—why is it now trying to call the caller? And for that matter, why doesn't that succeed?

I looked up the [GJS code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jdahlin/gjs/trunk/view/head:/modules/lang.js#L118) that generated `this.parent`, but I can't quite spot what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit more I found a way to fix it. In the GJS class model, the `parent` function is actually looking for the method's owner's superclass in order to call the method of the same name. Looks like every GJS class has a [wrapFunction](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jdahlin/gjs/trunk/view/head:/modules/lang.js#L172) helper that sets `_owner`. I used that to patch the function instead:

```
AltTab.AppSwitcherPopup.prototype._finish = AltTab.AppSwitcherPopup.wrapFunction('_finish', _modifiedFinish);
```